# (How) Can I infer a template type argument at one place and “just use” the inferred type elsewhere?

Tags: c++, templates, type-deduction

My function template has (among others) a function pointer (or a member function pointer) parameter. The function pointer may take any arguments, the argument types are being inferred. At the end of the parameter list, I want the function template to take the same parameters as the function pointer parameter.

```cpp
template<typename R, typename... Args>
void f(R(*fp)(Args...), Args... args);
```

The problems begin when the argument types do not match perfectly, e.g. let’s say `fp` takes a `Base*` and the caller to `f` gives you a `Derived*` or `fp` takes a `double` and the caller puts in `0` (of type `int`).

Is there any way to tell the compiler to infer `Args` solely based on `fp` and “just use” those inferred types for `args` and not try to match them based on the arguments they bind to?

Comment: Alternative: `template<typename Func, typename... Args> void f(Func f, Args&&... args);` and then inside the function you can use `std::invoke(f, std::forward<Args>(args)...)` to call the function.

Comment: Similar to what NathanOliver proposed, you can also deduce different `Args...` for the function and the actual arguments e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/Y4PvbcKso (with some extra SFINAE / concepts if you have multiple overloads).

Comment: @Holt, if you post this as an answer, it’s better visible (and people can vote on it).

Answer (score 6):

I found a solution that works. The term I did not know is [non-deduced context](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts). For example, everything to the left of the scope resolution operator `::` is non-deduced. In C++20, you can use `std::type_identity_t` to create such a context artificially, in C++14 and C++17, you can make your own `type_identity_t`.

So, you’d use

```cpp
template<typename R, typename... Args>
void f(R(*fp)(Args...), std::type_identity_t<Args>... args);
```

About perfect forwarding, when `fp` takes an argument by reference or value, `f` will do the same. With `std::forward`, a by-value parameter will be moved and a reference parameter will be referenced.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to deduce different types for both<sup>1</sup> and use a SFINAE or concepts to disable the overload when:

```cpp
// no SFINAE
template <typename R, typename... Args, typename... UArgs>
void f(R (*fp)(Args...), UArgs&&... args);

// SFINAE
template <typename R, typename... Args, typename... UArgs>
auto f(R (*fp)(Args...), UArgs&&... args)
    -> std::void_t<std::invoke_result_t<decltype(fp), UArgs...>>;

// concepts
template <typename R, typename... Args, typename... UArgs>
auto f(R (*fp)(Args...), UArgs&&... args)
    requires std::invocable<decltype(fp), UArgs...>;
```

One difference between this option and the [`std::type_identity` one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75941850/2666289) is when you call `f` with arguments that need a conversion for `fp`, e.g.

```
struct X { X(int); };
void f1(X);

f(&f1, 33); // implicit conversion from int to X
```

In the `std::type_identity` case, the conversion is done on the caller side (i.e., when you call `f`), while with the option above, the conversion is done when you invoke `fp` inside `f`.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> You could also use a generic function type, like proposed in the comments, depending on what you do inside `f()`.</sub>